# Woocommerce frontend orders filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am trying to filter the frontend orders of the customers based on the order ID, status and product name.

I've added a form with search box, added the query variable filter and as shown below.

```
    //Add my account order search keyword query var

function efst_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'keyword';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'efst_query_vars' );

// define the woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query callback 
function efst_filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query( $array ) { 
    $keyword = get_query_var('keyword');

    $array['post_parent'] =  $keyword;
    $array['post_status'] =  $keyword;

    return $array; 
}; 
         
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'efst_filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 10, 1 );
```

If I just use 'post_status' query filter and type a status like 'Processing' in the search box, it works. If I use 'Proces' or 'refu' it does not work. if I use both the search filters, search result is empty. That means, even the post status filter is inconsistent and other filters don't work at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the WP Query class I finally found the solution. WP uses a parameter "p" to search for the ID in the posts table.

Working code is below:

```
// define the woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query callback 
function efst_filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query( $array ) { 
    $keyword = get_query_var('keyword');
    $array['ID'] =  $keyword;
    return $array; 
}; 
         
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'efst_filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 10, 1 ); 


/**
 * Handle a custom 'ID' query var to get orders with the 'ID' meta.
 * @param array $query - Args for WP_Query.
 * @param array $query_vars - Query vars from WC_Order_Query.
 * @return array modified $query
 */
function handle_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['ID'] ) ) {
        $query['p'] = $query_vars['ID'];
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
```